# How to call methods from included php classes?

Tags: php

home.php

```
<?php 
include 'myClass.php';

$sampleClass=main;
$sampleClass->renderHtml();

?>
```

myClass.php

```
<?php
class main
{
    public $var="apple";

    public function renderHtml()
    {
        echo "This is $var";
        return;
    }
}
```

Now when I do that I receive an error and it says:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function renderHtml() on a 
non-object in C:\wamp\www\home.php on line 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include 'myClass.php';

// first create a new object
$sampleClass = new main();

// call object method
$sampleClass->renderHtml();
```

myClass.php

```
class main
{
    public $var = "apple";

    public function renderHtml()
    {
        echo "This is " . $this->var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: var in C:\wamp\www\myClass.php on line 8

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$sampleClass = new main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$sampleClass = new main();
```